# StreamWriter Access Denied on Windows Startup

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with StreamWriter, here's my code:

```
WebClient versionDownloader = new WebClient();
versionDownloader.DownloadFile("/* Version file here */", "EHWVBVersion.txt");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("EHWVBVersion.txt");
if (Version.Parse(reader.ReadLine()) > version)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("New version available ! Do you want to download it ?", "EHWVB", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        reader.Close();
        File.Delete("EHWVBVersion.txt");
        Process.Start("/* Download link Here */");
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
reader.Close();
File.Delete("EHWVBVersion.txt");
```

(Yes, there are actual links instead of comments in my code)

It's giving me an error mentioning Access Denied to "C:\WINDOWS\System32\EHWVBVersion.txt" even though I'm not wrtiting there. I guessed it had to so with something about temp file not loaded yet so I tried to print mentioned path before and tried, and nope, it is loaded.
So then I coded this function :

```
private void Log(string line)
{
    if (!File.Exists("EHWVB.log"))
        File.Create("EHWVB.log").Close();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("EHWVB.log", true);
    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " : " + line);
    writer.Close();
}
```

And tried to log everything that was accessing the version file.
I was quite surprise to discover that it isn't my version file that creates an issue or it's path, but the File Creation process directly. Same error, but for "C:\WINDOWS\System32\EHWVB.log" this time.

The thing is, if I try all this again not on Windows Startup, everything work fine. Version file is downloaded, logging works, etc.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can't you simply give it the full path to where you *want* it to put the file?

Comment: No because I want the software to be able to work anywhere.

Comment: I think I found the issue though, it's because of the working path because it's loaded on Windows Startup. I'm actually testing some code that changes the current path with a given -path argument.

Comment: Instead of *assuming* the path, use `Path.Combine` with your root path parameter to generate a correct, testable absolute path